# Regression to elucidate for specific effect of a treatment

Tags: regression, correlation, clinical-trials

Regression has commonly been used to adjust for baseline characteristics between groups in clinical trials. If a drug is known to cause effects (improvement) on A & B, and I am interested to elucidate whether the effect on A is independent of B, can I use regression to adjust for the improvement or endpoint scores of B?

Dependent (outcome) variable: Effect A.
Independent variables: Baseline characteristics and change in B scores.

Objective is to see if the drug has effect on A, independent of change in B scores. I was also thinking of analyzing correlation between A & B. Not sure if there are any other statistical techniques for this purpose. Any advice is appreciated. Thank you.